# Postfix/devcot MailServer - not receiving emails

Tags: configuration, dns, postfix

I'm new to linux and unix in general, I've worked with a shared hosting provider over the years where everything was setup for me, including email.

I'm now trying to create my own mail server in my VPS (where I'm moving everything I used to host under shared hosting), I'm running CentOS6 and followed the guide at: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix (I have my own domain - lets call it example.com)

Did everything step by step (acknowledging that sometimes I was just blindly following the steps), at the end I went ahead and created 2 new DNS records with my registrar: an **MX** record (example.com => mail.example.com) and an extra **A** record (mail.example.com=>VPS IP)

Doing a dig MX example.com gets me:

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41372
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.               IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        299     IN      MX      1 dc-8c1937cd-mail.example.com.

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Mar 29 14:36:20 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 66
```

I am frankly unsure what this "dc-8c1937cd-mail.example.com" MX record is, I would have expected it to be just "mail.example.com" as that is what I setup the record as (could this have anything to do with my old shared hosting settings? I have switched dns nameservers since moving to a VPS).

I have also tried sending a test email using telnet:

```
[root@server ~]# telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.exampe.com ESMTP Postfix
mail from: root@localhost
rcpt to: user@example.com
data
Subject: My first mail on Postfix

test!
.250 2.1.0 Ok
250 2.1.5 Ok
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
```

The response seems OK, but I've checked both **/var/mail/user** and **/var/spool/mail/user** for emails and see nothing (my user file is indeed in these folders both files are empty)

Any idea where I went wrong and how to find the problem?

postconf -n results:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relay_domains =
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: check the `ns` record for ur domain to know if your nameservers had changed or not. Post the log lines generated by postfix in `/var/log/maillog` and the output of `postconf -n`

Comment: Hey, I've added my postconf -n results and the maillog, cheers.

Comment: It appears I was doing my telnet commands wrong, after some googling I now seem to be receiving emails using telnet - the problem now is, I don't get any emails if using from external sources (like gmail for example).

Comment: Your `MX` records should be proper for receiving external mails.